# Web Browser Control in window application

Tags: winforms

Hello i am using this code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");

        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.Write("<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.");
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.Write("<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b>");
    }
```

but when i clicked on button then webBrowser1 show blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strText = "<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.";
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        HtmlDocument objHtmlDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        objHtmlDoc.Write(String.Empty);
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = strText;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strText="<b><i>My Name</i> is Not </b> Khan.<b>";
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        HtmlDocument objHtmlDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        objHtmlDoc.Write(String.Empty);
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = strText;
    }
```